# How to change (adjust) dropout rate of loaded model in Keras (tensorflow backend)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to change the dropout rate of a loaded model in Keras (tf backend).

It seems changing it via this method below, only changes the keras model, and the changes aren't reflected in the backend.

```
#after model is loaded

model.layers[-3].rate = .7  # -3 layer is the dropout layer
```

These changes are superficial and don't reach the backend.

I tried to playaround with the backend layers, but couldn't figure out how to make the change.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.gergltd.com/home/2018/03/changing-dropout-on-the-fly-during-training-time-test-time-in-keras/

Comment: @cpury I remember trying it. I'm not sure if it worked. I will have to go back to my model when I get a chance. I'm currently working on some iOS stuff but will report back when I play around with the model again.